# application is installed but not started. "Application is not installed"

Tags: android

Maybe someone has encountered this problem.
There is an Android application written in Eclipse, exported to the APK (tried it signed or not).
APK is installed and running on Android platform 2.3.
But on 3.2 honeycomb is installed on the platform, there is a shortcut in the programs at startup says "application is not installed".
Debug on the emulator running from ECLIPSE is working good, but not run from shortcut.
For 3 weeks I can not find the answer.

Here my mainfest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="vassa.PrexAg"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">    
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>


<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/agent">
<activity android:name=".Logon"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity> 
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="login" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
<activity android:name="Settings" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
<activity android:name="Zakaz" android:noHistory="false"></activity>
<activity android:name="calc" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
<activity android:noHistory="true" android:name="vzm"></activity>
<activity android:noHistory="true" android:name="fo" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
<activity android:name="ShowCel" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
<activity android:name="SettCel" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
<activity android:name="contextm" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:noHistory="false"></activity>
<activity android:name="mess" android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
<activity android:name="comment" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
<activity android:name="Geni"></activity>
<activity android:name="Ocenka" android:noHistory="true"></activity>



</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. just need remove android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" for activity .Logon